# General steps to add button to page in NetSuite?

Tags: user-interface, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

could anyone please, assist me with a request to add a button to an Estimate form?
I need only general steps on how to do it (although I'd appreciate if someone provided more details).
I tried to create a client script, but it doesn't have the 'N/ui/serverWidget' module (apparently it's not available in the client scripts).

How otherwise I can create a button w/o creating a mess and directly modifying the DOM — I don't know.

This is how it should look:
[image: custom button in NetSuite]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `beforeLoad()` event in a User Event script to add the button to the record's form.  You can also specify a client script, which will contain the logic to be executed when the button is clicked.

```
let form = context.form;
form.clientScriptModulePath = '{{pathToYourClientScript}}';
form.addButton({
    label: 'This is the button label',
    id: 'custpage_button_id',
    functionName: 'functionFromYourClientScript'
});
```

The User Event script needs to be deployed on your target record type (Estimate).  The client script does not need to be deployed for this; it just has to be available in the file cabinet at the location specified in the `form.clientScriptModulePath` parameter.  You can optionally specify the client script using the `clientScriptFileId` property instead.  The `functionName` property specifies the function from your client script, which will be bound to the button.  This (client) function will execute when the button is clicked.