# In Netuite, is it possible to run a suitescript when a standard button is pressed?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In Netsuite, I want to run a suitescript when a standard button on a transaction record is pressed. Example 'Mark Shipped' button on item fulfillment. Is it possible?

I have tried a client script but it works only when you edit the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't arbitrarily run a script on just any native button, but in the example you give you can use a User Event script to fire on the `ship` event.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([], function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
      beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    };

    function beforeSubmit(context) {
    
        if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.SHIP) { return; }

        //code to run when Item Fulfillment is marked shipped goes here.
    }
});
```

Other "action" buttons like Approve, Cancel and Print and so on also fire events that you can listen for.  See [context.UserEventType](https://suiteanswers.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44548) in SuiteAnswers for a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

*My conclusion is — no it's not possible.* Unless of course one creates some really nasty things, like accessing the DOM directly (which I would never do).

**So the most reasonable thing to do will be:**

- add a custom button, which would do what you need
- try to hide the standard button, if it's that needed.

---

The conclusion is based on the 2 premises:

- I recently asked a question about how to add a button with a click handler [General steps to add button to page in NetSuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76678879/general-steps-to-add-button-to-page-in-netsuite) and from the answer it follows that the only[?] way to do it is by setting the click handler on the serverWidget.button instance (accessed via the return value of the `context.form.addButton()` method), when you add it in a UserEvent script deployed on a record type.

  ```
  /**
   * @NApiVersion 2.x
   * @NScriptType UserEventScript
   * @NModuleScope SameAccount
   */

  define([], function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
      beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };

    function beforeLoad(context) {
      var form = context.form;
      form.clientScriptModulePath = '/SuiteScripts/foo.js';
      form.addButton({
        label: 'Foo',
        id: 'custpage_foo',
        functionName: 'fooClickHandler'
      });
    }
  });
  ```
- but if the button already exists, there is no way in the API to set a handler on it. As you can see there is nothing like `Button.functionName` or `Button.modify()` in the SuiteScript API, even if you manage to get the button via its id like `_back`:

[image: serverWidget.Button API contents]

And the docs don't mention anything appropriate (https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2857647.html).

So the answer is no, it's not possible.