# Add Custom Button to Complete CRM Task in Netsuite

Tags: javascript, task, netsuite, crm

I am trying to add a button that only allows to complete the task if a custom field of the form has a fixed value, if not, alert the user that it is not possible to complete it.

```html
define([], function() {
  function completeTaskIfCustomFieldIsTrue() {
    var customFieldId = 'custeventcrm_sales_status'; // Replace with the actual custom field ID
    var isCustomFieldTrue = document.getElementById(customFieldId).value;
    var isStatus = 'status'; //FieldID of status task

    if (isCustomFieldTrue == 6) {
      // Custom field is true, complete the CRM task
      // Add your code here to complete the CRM task
       button.onclick = function() {
        window.location.href = 'sb2.app.netsuite.com/app/crm/calendar/task.nl?id=|| {internal_id} ||&whence=&cmid=1692983702342_16261';
        var isStaus = 'COMPLETE'; // Replace with the desired status

        changeTaskStatus(taskId, newStatus);
  };

  // Append the button to the form
  var form = document.getElementById('custform_200_5210436_sb2_536'); // Replace with the actual form ID
  form.appendChild(button);
    } else {
      // Custom field is not true, do nothing
      window.alert('Custom field is not true. Skipping CRM task...');
    }
  }
  return {
    pageInit: function(context) {
      completeTaskIfCustomFieldIsTrue();
    }
  };
});
```

I added this code, but it doesn't stick completely in the field

Could something similar be added to the saved search?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite does not support or recommend DOM manipulation on NetSuite pages.  The official stance is that all changes made to the page must be done using their documented APIs. The normal way to achieve this would be to add a button using a User Event `beforeLoad()` function, and bind the button to a function contained in a client script, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680879/7885772).

HTH.