# SuiteScript > add button and then transform record > getting an error

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm currently looking for cheat sheets for NetSuite SuiteScripts if there are. And I'm getting an error in my code when I press the button.

my code function is to add a button to a record then transform the record to another record. Unfortunately, im getting this error in the console **Uncaught ReferenceError: transformToCreditNote is not defined**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/record', 'N/url'], function(serverWidget, record, url) {
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (context.type === context.UserEventType.VIEW) {
            var form = context.form;

            // Create a button to transform to Credit Memo
            form.addButton({
                id: 'custpage_transform_to_credit_note',
                label: 'Transform to Credit Note',
                functionName: 'transformToCreditNote'
            });

            // Define the function to transform and redirect
            function transformToCreditNote() {
                var currentRecord = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.INVOICE,
                    id: context.newRecord.id
                });

                // Transform the Sales Invoice to a Credit Memo
                var creditMemo = currentRecord.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                    toType: record.Type.CREDIT_MEMO
                });

                // Save the Credit Memo
                var creditMemoId = creditMemo.save();

                // Redirect to the newly created Credit Memo
                var creditMemoURL = url.resolveRecord({
                    recordType: record.Type.CREDIT_MEMO,
                    recordId: creditMemoId,
                    isEditMode: true,
                });

                // Redirect to the Credit Memo
                window.location.href = creditMemoURL;
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});
```

I'm trying to add a button to a record then when clicked it will transform the record and redirects the user to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'll explain the reason, why the error is happening from the ECMA Script point of view.

You call the `form.addButton()` method and pass it the string, not the function. And **the scope of the `addButton()` method is defined by the place, where it's defined, not where it's called.**

And when the `.addButton()` runs, it sees only the `'transformToCreditNote'` string, but there is no function with such a name in its scope (because its present only in the scope of the `function beforeLoad` declaration) that's why you get the ReferenceError error.

---

Here is what you need to do to get rid of the **Uncaught ReferenceError: transformToCreditNote is not defined** error.

You need to define your click handler function in a client script and set it on the `form` object as a property. As far as I know, it's a must (sorry, cannot provide any reference to the docs).

So you need to have 2 scripts:

- a user event one, which would add the button and set the client script's path on the `form`.
- a client one, which would define the handler

Here is you UserEvent script, deploy it on the record, on whose page you wish to have the button (**note the path to your client script**, which you would place in the SuiteScripts directory (and subdirectories, if needed)):

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define([], function() {
    'use strict';
    function beforeLoad(context) {
        if (context.type === context.UserEventType.VIEW) {
            var form = context.form;
            form.clientScriptModulePath = '/SuiteScripts/my-client-script.js';
            // Create a button to transform to Credit Memo
            form.addButton({
                id: 'custpage_transform_to_credit_note',
                label: 'Transform to Credit Note',
                functionName: 'transformToCreditNote'
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad: beforeLoad
    };
});
```

And here is the ClientScript:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/url'], function(record, url) {
    'use strict';
    return {
      //You must have this
      pageInit: function() {},
      transformToCreditNote: function() {
          var currentRecord = record.load({
              type: record.Type.INVOICE,
              id: context.newRecord.id
          });

          // Transform the Sales Invoice to a Credit Memo
          var creditMemo = currentRecord.transform({
              fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
              toType: record.Type.CREDIT_MEMO
          });

          // Save the Credit Memo
          var creditMemoId = creditMemo.save();

          // Redirect to the newly created Credit Memo
          var creditMemoURL = url.resolveRecord({
              recordType: record.Type.CREDIT_MEMO,
              recordId: creditMemoId,
              isEditMode: true,
          });

          // Redirect to the Credit Memo
          window.location.href = creditMemoURL;
      }
    };
});
```

Can't vouch for the correctness of the scripts, but **the mentioned error should be gone**

Comment: Thank you so much for providing some insights I did copy and pasted the codes you've provided and I'm getting a console error context is not defined (I believe this is on the client script). I get your point I'm just recalling how to do suitescript and it's delaying me in my progress. Is there a way I can access resources about SutieScript Samples?

Comment: @FMFM I believe you'll have even more errors, because looking at your original script I really doubt if `context.newRecord` will be present, when the UserEventType is VIEW. Logically it should be present only on a CREATE event.

Comment: @FMFM regarding the resources you asked, I really don't know. After working for over 2 years with NetSuite it's still a mystery for me how to do one thing or another. Usually it's Netsuite Help, but I personally failed to find there how to add a custom button to a record page and was forced to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76678879/general-steps-to-add-button-to-page-in-netsuite

Comment: @FMFM ask a question here about the resources. Here is a user named Krypton, he seems pretty authoritative on NetSuite. He might be able to provide a more useful advice on where to get information about the overall NetSuite customization howtos.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my thread and giving some advice as well. Have a wonderful week!